# Get stored procedure resultset inside another stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have multiples stored procedures that uses the same subquery in IN clauses. The subquery select a list of IDs. My reflex was to go a ahead and create a new stored procedure containing this subquery to define it in a single place, and use it inside the others procedures. Now I realize that I cannot get the resultset from the subquery when calling the stored procedure... I searched and found no alternatives other than defining a temporary table, which I found overkill to get a couples Ids. Is there something I'm missing or I simply cannot do this in MYSQL?

To illustrate my problem:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE subquery()
BEGIN   
    SELECT id from example; # returns a list of IDs
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure1()
BEGIN   
    SELECT * from example2 WHERE id IN (CALL subquery()); # No go, syntax error
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE procedure2()
BEGIN
    SET @resultSet = CALL subquery();
    SELECT * from example2 WHERE id IN (@resultSet); # No go, syntax error
END;
```

Of course the real subquery is a big chunk of SQL that I prefer to maintain in a single place.

As I understand it, I can't use Functions as they only returns scalars values, and I can't use OUT parameters as they don't allow resultsets.

What are my alternatives here other than multiplying subqueries or using temporary table as defined [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61530/how-do-i-access-a-result-set-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure)?

Comment: Noway. SELECT output is sent to *stdout* directly, you cannot access it / use it as rowsource. Intermediate (temporary) table is the only option. Of course, in some special cases the rowset can be serialized (for example in JSON) in slave procedure, returned as scalar OUT parameter and parsed to rowset in main procedure.

Comment: Thanks, although not the answer I was hoping for :) I will then probably duplicate subqueries even if I dont like to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Unfotunatelly you cannot use a stored procedure output inside another stored procedure in MySQL. But if your subquery does not require parameters the best option (in my opinion) is a VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS select id from example;
```

and then you can reference your view as a table (inside other stored procs as well):

```
SELECT * from example2 WHERE id IN (select id from myView);
```

Answer (score 0):

For how to return tables from one stored procedure to another, this existing Stack Exchange answer helped me:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/270887/61926

It works by using known-named temporary tables (which are, at least, unique per-connection).